# Elasticsearch - query building - is this the correct way of doing it?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document which looks like this:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "orgnr": "1"
  },
  "bar": {
    "orgnr" : "2"
  },
  "created": "2015-02-12",
  ...  
}
```

I have an API where a user can query for:

- orgnr (required)
- role (optional) - ANY by default ANY means  must match at least one of bar.orgnr or foo.orgnr, but could also be role:BAR, and then it must match bar.orgnr:
- created (optional)
- query (optional)

Orgnr **must match** foo.orgnr OR bar.orgnr, and can then have a lot of other field and text queries. I match this doing a query string query. So for a request where orgnr is 1, the following query string would be generated:

> (foo.orgnr:1 OR bar.orgnr:1) AND (rest of query)

Where rest of query can be for example

- created:[2015-01-01 TO *]
- created:[2015-01-01 TO *] AND *query*

But i'm not sure this is actually the correct way or doing this. Reading https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_queries_and_filters.html makes me insecure. 
I could also use a boolean match, with must for the orgnr.

With role:BAR the following query would be generated:

> (bar.orgnr:1) AND (rest of query)

The most important here is that orgnr is actually matched towards foo OR bar orgnr.
**Or should I use a filter for this instead?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [bool query in filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-bool-query.html) is a fine way of doing it. The Should requires at least one clause to match.

```
POST _search
{
   "query": {
      "constant_score": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "should": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "foo.orgnr": "1"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "bar.orgnr": "1"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's a fine way, but what's the actuall difference? I mean, constructing a query string with AND and OR is far mor simpiler for me.

Comment: The Lucene query syntax is shorter than the Elasticsearch Query DSL syntax, but for complicated queries the readability of the Lucene syntax is lower. If you go with the Lucene syntax and let clients enter the search query then you should take extra care when sanitizing the input.